# How to set $config['sess_expiration'] codeigniter from model?

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I set the session destroy from the setting of user?

CONFIG

```
$ses_destroy = $this->loginmodel->set_session_destroy();

$config['sess_expiration'] = $ses_destroy;
```

MODEL

```
function sessions_destroy_user(){

  return echo '30';

}
```

Comment: Ccould you give me the alternative way?

Comment: I didn't understand what are trying to do? is it that you want the user to edit the time of the session expiration in an input field in his setting form?

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->session->sess_expiration = '14400';// expires in 4 hours
$this->session->set_userdata($data);// set session
```